# Can't find package X11 on WSL

Tags: cmake, x11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to build an opensource project on WSL using cmake.
I'm getting first these two errors which I don't understand :

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:185 (configure_file):
 configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:210 (configure_file):
 configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

and for X11:

```
Searching X11
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_LIB)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
 /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindX11.cmake:366 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
 CMakeLists.txt:18 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Here is the cmakelist.txt provided :

```
#CMake for the gard Project
project(GARD)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.0)

#Set the path to the Cmake Modules
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/")
MESSAGE("Path to Cmake Modules is " ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

MESSAGE("The source directory of the project is " ${GARD_SOURCE_DIR})


MESSAGE("")
MESSAGE("STEP 1 : SEARCHING FOR NEEDED MODULES")
MESSAGE("")

MESSAGE("Searching X11")
FIND_PACKAGE(X11 REQUIRED)
IF(X11_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(" X11 include path: " ${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})
    MESSAGE(" X11 library path: " ${X11_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF(X11_FOUND)

MESSAGE("Searching LAPACK AND BLAS")
find_package(LAPACK)
IF(LAPACK_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(" LAPACK library path: " ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
    MESSAGE(" BLAS library path: " ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF(LAPACK_FOUND)

MESSAGE("Searching CIMG")
find_package(CImg)
IF(CIMG_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(" CIMG include path: " ${CIMG_INCLUDE_DIR})
ENDIF(CIMG_FOUND)

MESSAGE("Searching pthread")
FIND_LIBRARY(PTHREADS_LIBRARY pthread
  PATHS /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  )
IF(PTHREADS_LIBRARY)
    MESSAGE(" Pthread library path: " ${PTHREADS_LIBRARY})
ENDIF(PTHREADS_LIBRARY)

MESSAGE("Searching Graphviz")
find_package(GraphViz)
IF(GRAPHVIZ_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(" Graphviz library path: " ${GRAPHVIZ_LIBRARIES})
    MESSAGE(" Graphviz include path: " ${GRAPHVIZ_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(GRAPHVIZ_SUPPORT "#define GRAPHVIZ_SUPPORT")
ENDIF(GRAPHVIZ_FOUND)

CONFIGURE_FILE(GraphVizConfig.h.cmake ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/core/GraphVizConfig.h) 

find_package(OpenMP)
if(OPENMP_FOUND)
    message("openMP found")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

MESSAGE("Searching FLANN")
find_package(Flann)
IF(FLANN_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(" FLANN include path: " ${FLANN_INCLUDE_DIR})
    include_directories(${FLANN_INCLUDE_DIR})
    SET(FLANN_SUPPORT "#define FLANN_SUPPORT")
ELSE(FLANN_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(" FLANN include path not found")
    SET(FLANN_SUPPORT "")
ENDIF(FLANN_FOUND)

include(ProcessorCount)
ProcessorCount(N)

if(NOT N EQUAL 0)
    set(AVAILABLE_CORES "#define AVAILABLE_CORES ${N}")
else(NOT N EQUAL 0)
    set(AVAILABLE_CORES "#define AVAILABLE_CORES 1")
endif()

CONFIGURE_FILE(FlannConfig.h.cmake ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/core/FlannConfig.h)

MESSAGE("")

MESSAGE("")
MESSAGE("STEP 2 : SET INCLUDE AND LIBRARY PATHS")
MESSAGE("")
SET(GARD_INCLUDE_DIR    ${GARD_SOURCE_DIR}/include)


IF(LAPACK_FOUND)
    SET(LINK_LIBRARIES ${X11_LIBRARIES} ${PTHREADS_LIBRARY} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES} ${BLAS_LIBRARIES} ${GRAPHVIZ_LIBRARIES})
    SET(CIMG_USE_LAPACK "#define cimg_use_lapack")
ELSE()
    SET(LINK_LIBRARIES ${X11_LIBRARIES} ${PTHREADS_LIBRARY} ${GRAPHVIZ_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF()

CONFIGURE_FILE(CimgConfig.h.cmake ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/core/CimgConfig.h)

MESSAGE("")
MESSAGE("STEP 3 : Documentation generation")
MESSAGE("")

MESSAGE("Searching DOXYGEN")
INCLUDE(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/FindDoxygen.cmake)
IF(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    MESSAGE("DOXYGEN Dir " ${DOXYGEN_DIR})
    MESSAGE("GENERATING DOCUMENTATION")
    SET(ENV{GARD_INCLUDE_DIR} "${GARD_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
    EXEC_PROGRAM("cd docs;${DOXYGEN_DIR}/doxygen doc.txt"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE MY_OUTPUT
    )
ENDIF(DOXYGEN_FOUND)

MESSAGE(STATUS "Link libraries:  ${LINK_LIBRARIES}")


MESSAGE("")
MESSAGE("STEP 4 : COMPILATION")
MESSAGE("")


add_subdirectory (${GARD_SOURCE_DIR}/examples)
# add_subdirectory (${GARD_SOURCE_DIR}/operators)
```

Can you help please? I'm new to cmake and WSL. I'm running WSL on Windows 10 and I've installed the X11 library with " sudo apt-get install libx11-dev "  . The command 'cmake .' is running in the bash terminal and looks like :

```
ananass@DESKTOP-R1E6G2S:/mnt/c/Users/ananass/gard$
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to understand what is going on. Please provide the CMake commands you ran that produced these errors, and show where you are running these commands on your system. Also, please provide your CMake code in the question post as text.

Comment: I've edited according to your recommandations